# Using @autowire annotation in spring boot is throwing 'BeanCreationException'

Tags: java, spring, rest, maven, spring-boot

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'daaSController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: com.ca.mock.dass.storage.mockservice.StorageService com.ca.mock.daas.storage.controller.DaaSController.storageService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.ca.mock.dass.storage.mockservice.StorageService] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true), @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier(value=storageService)}
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:301)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1186)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:706)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:762)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482)
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:109)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:691)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:320)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:952)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:941)
at com.ca.mock.daas.storage.controller.Application.main(Application.java:15)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: com.ca.mock.dass.storage.mockservice.StorageService com.ca.mock.daas.storage.controller.DaaSController.storageService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.ca.mock.dass.storage.mockservice.StorageService] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true), @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier(value=storageService)}
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:522)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:298)
... 16 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.ca.mock.dass.storage.mockservice.StorageService] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true), @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier(value=storageService)}
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1118)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:967)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:862)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:494)
... 18 common frames omitted
```

Code related to this error:

**Application.java**

```
package com.ca.mock.daas.storage.controller;

import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

import com.ca.mock.dass.storage.mockservice.StorageServiceMockImpl;

@ComponentScan
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class Application {
   public static void main(final String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
   }
}
```

**DaaSController.java**

```
package com.ca.mock.daas.storage.controller;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.ca.mock.dass.storage.mockservice.StorageService;


@RestController
public class DaaSController {

    private static final String V1_DAAS = "/v1/daas";
   private static final String APPLICATION_JSON_CHARSET_UTF_8 =   "application/json; charset=utf-8";



  @Autowired
  @Qualifier("storageService")
  StorageService storageService;


  @RequestMapping(value = V1_DAAS, produces = APPLICATION_JSON_CHARSET_UTF_8)
  public String cecs() {
        return storageService.cecs();
  }
}
```

**StorageService.java**

```
package com.ca.mock.dass.storage.mockservice;


public interface StorageService {


    String cecs();

}
```

**StorageServiceImpl.java**

```
package com.ca.mock.dass.storage.mockservice;


public class StorageServiceMockImpl implements StorageService {


    @Override
    public String cecs() {
        return DassStorageUtil.mockDasdWithMetrics("Cecs");
    }
```

**DassStorageUtil has code to read from a file and return a string.**

**application-context.xml**

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"       xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
   xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
   xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.2.xsd
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee 
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-3.2.xsd 
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.2.xsd 
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/task
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task-3.2.xsd">

       <context:component-scan base-package="com.ca.mock.daas.storage.controller"/>
       <context:annotation-config />
       <bean id="daaSController" class="com.ca.mock.daas.storage.controller.DaaSController"/>
       <bean id="storageService" class="com.ca.mock.dass.storage.mockservice.StorageServiceMockImpl"/>

</beans>
```

Can someone please help me with this error.

Comment: Why did you post `application-context.xml`? Nothing in your code seems to use it.

Comment: How to link this as I'm having my beans defined in application-context.xml

Comment: May be that is the reason why I'm getting "NoSuchBeanDefinitionException" although I defined then in application-context.xml

Comment: Please post your web.xml as well to see how you bootstrap Spring.

Comment: @CodeRunner There is no web.xml. This is Spring Boot. Everything is done automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're intending to use the XML configuration, you need to import that resource

```
@ComponentScan
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ImportResource("application-context.xml")
public class Application {
   public static void main(final String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
   }
}
```

Comment: Is there any specific location to keep this xml file in maven project structure?

Comment: @user2613399 The way I've presented in my answer expects the file at the root of your application's classpath. If you want to put it elsewhere, in some other package, you'll need to modify the `String`, `"/com/example/application-context.xml". In a maven project, it would go to the corresponding `/src/main/resources`.

Comment: Although I place it in src/main/resources I'm getting the below error:               Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: IOException parsing XML document from class path resource [application-context.xml]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [application-context.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:344)

Comment: @user2613399 Are you sure you don't have a typo in the naming? Make sure that Maven is compiling and building your application correctly. You should have the file at the root of the classpath when you start your Java process.